# TAILS or FREEPTO is better to stay anonymous on the net?

Tags: network

Which is safest for security and being anonymous in internet?

I have heard TAILS is better because it was used by Snowden, but I don't really know FREEPTO.

Comment: If your not too familiar with linux use tails for better (google) support.

Comment: This type of question is explicitly off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main difference in between Tails and Freepto, is that Tails routes everything through Tor, you have no way to disable this. Freepto does not anonymise your computer IP unless you choose to do that.
>
> The projects have different targets, Freepto’s goal is to allow for a highly portable operating system and switch people from proprietary software into open source. The privacy tools that Freepto includes are there because activists need them to communicate safely, as an extra, not as the reason for the operating system. Tails reason to exist on the other hand, is to provide anonymity.
>
> If what you want is a portable easy to use OS with discretionary high calibre privacy tools, use Freepto, if you are paranoid about privacy and want everything to be anonymous, then use Tails.

Also:

> The operating system is fully encrypted with LUKS, you will be asked for a password before it boots, ...

http://www.hacker10.com/internet-anonymity/encrypted-operating-system-for-activists-freepto/